# Calculating distance between two vectors using Paillier homomorphic encryption

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption, paillier

I am basically trying to perform euclidean distance calculation in the encrypted domain (Paillier encryption). Using the homomorphic properties of Paillier, the squared euclidean distance formula can be written as ([paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Erkin_Zekeriya/publication/221655685_Privacy-Preserving_Face_Recognition/links/00b7d51879c63915ac000000.pdf)):

$\newcommand{\opn}{\operatorname}$
$$\underbrace{\opn{Enc}\left(\sum^d_{i=1}p_i^2\right)}_{\text{(I)}}\cdot \underbrace{\opn{Enc}\left(\sum^d_{i=1}q_i^2\right)}_{\text{(II)}}\cdot \underbrace{\prod^d_{i=1}\opn{Enc}(q_i)^{-2p_i}}_{\text{(III)}}$$

I tried implementing this in matlab using two sample vectors `a` and `b` but I seem to be getting a completely wrong distance when decrypted. The euclidean distance of the two vectors without encryption is `100.5883` but when applying the above formula and then decrypting the result I get `10118`

```
%I'm using the variable precision integer toolbox (vpi) to handle large numbers in Matlab
a = [10, 58, 23, 59, 78, 11];
b = [87, 15, 12, 32, 41, 22];

p = 708481;
q = 708497;
r = 461563;

n = p * q;

% calculating (I) from above equation, i.e. a^2
encA =vpi(zeros(size(A))); %initialize vector for encrypted values
sumA = 0;

for i=1:length(A)
    encA(i) = PaillierEncrypt(A(i), p, q, random_r); %this will encrypt the value at index i in the vector
    sumA = sumA + (A(i))^2;
end

enc_sumA = PaillierEncrypt(sumA, p, q, random_r); %now encrypt the summed value



% below is for (II) and (III) in the equation i.e. b^2 -2ab
encB =vpi(zeros(size(B)));
sumB = 0;
enc_prodAB = vpi(1);

for i=1:length(B)
    encB(i) = PaillierEncrypt(B(i), p, q, random_r);
    sumB = sumB + (B(i))^2;

%the below block is to assist in determining the mod of a negative exponent, basically it allows for this to run without error: mod((encA)^(-2*vpi(B)), n*n);
    a2 = encA(i); %the encrypted base
    d2 = (-2)*vpi(B(i)); %the exponent that is a non encrypted scalar
    n3 = n*n;

    negpowermod = @(a,d,n2) minv(powermod(a,abs(d),n2),n2); 

    result = negpowermod(a2,d2,n3);

    enc_prodAB = enc_prodAB * result;
end

enc_sumB = PaillierEncrypt(sumB, p, q, random_r);

dist = enc_sumA * enc_sumB * enc_prodAB;
```

Ive commented the above code as best I could to explain what I am doing. I'm sure I messed up the implementation somehow.

Some guidance would really be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Other issues, in no particular order: `n3` is used where `n2` should be. Passing `p`and `q`as separate parameter to `PaillierEncrypt` is a huge design mistake showing a lack of understanding of what public/private key is about. Why compute the `encB(i)` when they do not get used? Not using `encB(i)` is correct if and only if the `b`are the $p_i$, but choosing that convention is an accident waiting to happen. A 40-bit `n` is dozens times too small for even mild security; execution time grows roughly as the cube of that; thus execution time may be underestimated by thousands...

Comment: ...To demonstrate something useful, the encryption of whatever the $q_i$ are must be done first, then the result passed to a party holding the $p_i$, which the code does not illustrate. What about modular reduction of `enc_prodAB `and friends like the final `enc_sumB`? If `a`and `A`are the same thing, use the same case. How does `random_r`get an approriate random value? Is not that logically the job of `PaillierEncrypt`to draw a random value, trimming a parameter and encapsulating encryption better? Ad nauseam.

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks for the detailed response. At the time I am interested in the implementation of euclidean distance in Paillier I am currently not targeting security or execution time. The values selected are random values just for the sake of getting this to work. At implementation stage I will focus on security, but right now I am teaching myself this and was hoping on understanding why my implementation was not working.. Also ``n3`` is the same as ``n2`` I just gave created a separate variable for my own clarity.

Comment: If "`n3` is the same as `n2`" "for clarity", and the code contains affectation of `n` then `n3 = n*n` but no affectation of `n2`, I quit reviewing it. I'm still happy I learned that application of Paillier encryption where we can compute Euclidean distance between two points known by two respective parties, and have a third one decipher the outcome.

Comment: I'm glad this question helped you learn something but I'm still where I was yesterday. :( - Also ``n2`` was used in an anonymous function ``negpowermod`` and since it was used there I did not want to pass value to it using the same variable name.. It would have worked but it would still have been clearer to use a different variable than the one used in the function handle.. thats why I used ``n3`` to pass in the value to ``n2``. Thats what I meant by ``for clarity``

Comment: How is the multiplication of two encrypted number is possible? Since they implemented only the multiplication of encrypted to scalar, I don't know how this code is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see your problem.
10118 is indeed the square of the euclidian distance ~100.5883

Comment: oh my.. I dont know how I missed that.. how embarrassing.. Im glad that my implementation is correct. Many thanks for pointing that out